# Comparing tuple contents with int in python

Tags: python, list

```
a = [(0, "Hello"), (1,"My"), (3, "Is"), (2, "Name"), (4, "Jacob")]
```

This is an example of a list, but when I try to this this it doesn't work:

```
if time < a[3]:
    print ("You did it!")
```

The problem is that I can't apparently compare a tuple with an int, but I only want to compare it to the first number in the tuple. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This?

```
if time < a[3][0]:
#              ^
    print ("You did it!")
```

You can index the tuple the same way you did with the list.

Comment: It worked, but is there a way to sort that list in descending order? I try to sort it but I get TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str() and I tried using your [] tip

Comment: If you're sorting w.r.t the numbers then `sorted(a, reverse=True)` should do.